# Vetor recebe valores de maneira errada

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb

Olá, eu estou utilizando angular e pouchdb para inserir valor em um vetor.
porém atualmente com o código abaixo na hora de usar o comando       `console.log(vetorPrincipal);` ele retorna assim 
[image: screenshot, vetor retornando de forma errada]

O correto seria retornar assim

[image: Exibindo corretamente]

Meu código e esse abaixo.

```
 var vetorPrincipal = [];
 insereNoVetor();
  console.log(vetorPrincipal);      
 function insereNoVetor() {
   // verifica se variaveis estão preenchidas, se estiverem então Zera
   if(vetorPrincipal[0] != undefined) {
     vetorPrincipal = [];
     jk = [];
   };
   if($scope.relatorioX.LeituraRelatorio[0] == "todos"){
     $pouchDB.find("relatorio", $scope.relatorioX.IDRelatorio).then(function (resultado) {
       return resultado.docs
     }).then(function (vetor) {
        angular.forEach(vetor, function(vale, key){
          $pouchDB.findleiturasRelatorio(vale._id).then(function (valor) {
            angular.forEach(valor.docs, function (v,k) {
              vetorPrincipal.push(v);
            });
          });

        });

     });
   }else{
     angular.forEach($scope.relatorioX.LeituraRelatorio, function (v,k) {
       $pouchDB.findleiturasRelatorio(v).then(function (resultado) {
         angular.forEach(resultado.docs, function (o,p) {
           vetorPrincipal.push(o);
         });
       });
     });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, a solução foi usar a função `$watch` do angular. basicamente eu fiz.

```
         $scope.$watch('vetorPrincipal['+cont+']', function() {
            //  alert(JSON.stringify(likkkk));
            console.log(cont);
            // alert($scope.likkkk);
            paraExibirGrafico();
         });
```

`var cont ; \\ Essa var diz o tamanho do vetor.`
Assim que tem uma mudança na ultima posição do vetor o metodo `paraExibirGrafico()` e chamado, passado o  vetor de maneira correta.